# Listening to Neo4j Lucene index changes

Tags: neo4j, lucene

I have a HA setup of embedded Neo4j 2.3.2 databases, that use a legacy Lucene index for storing data. I would now like to be able to listen for changes in that index so that I would be able to push changes to the client only when the index changes.

Because this is a HA setup, the transaction that changes the index might not be on the machine that is doing the polling, so if I understand correctly, I can't solve this by just using a `TransactionEventHandler`.

Is there any other way to monitor the Lucene index for changes without repeatedly doing queries to the index?

Ideally I would just register a callback to the index, which would be fired when the index changes, but I haven't found such a method from either Lucene or Neo4j. Also I have been trying to access the Lucene index from Neo4j but can only get as far as `org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy[Node]` that is returned from `gds.index().forNodes("myIndex")`.

Having the server query the index for updates every second for every connected client seems like it would become really CPU intensive at some point.

Answer (score 0):

#### Correction

The tx listener will called on the machine that initiated the transaction which can be the master (and should be) but if you started your tx on a slave the tx-listener will be called there.

Afaik there are no ways currently to monitor Lucene changes directly.

What kind of changes do you want to detect / push?

Comment: For example when a new item is added to the index on the master node, and there are long polls from clients on the slave nodes. I'd like to know about the new item on the slave node preferably at the same time the master pushes (via the HA process) the change to the slave, so that the slave can send the new data on the long poll connection.

In my HA setup the master node gets all the setters, and the slaves handle getters. So really every single update to the index I want to monitor on the slave machine, is done via HA push from master to slave.

Comment: And why? To block your reads until the index update is applied? You could also just use sticky sessions/transactions and send reads of updated values to the master.

Comment: Say I have two clients: client1, client2 and three servers nodeMaster, nodeSlave1 and nodeSlave2. Now client1 and client2 want to stay in sync, so they both have a long poll to nodeSlave1 and nodeSlave2 respectively. Now client1 updates with PUT "example" which is written to nodeMaster, and index is updated. HA process then pushed the change to both slaves. Now to get client2 to be in sync as fast as possible, I'd like to know when the index changed on nodeSlave1 to return the "example" value to client2. In a cluster, there is no way to guarantee that both clients are long polling nodeMaster.

Comment: The setup I have is the recommended one: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-haproxy.html - "If you are able to distinguish in your application between requests that write, and requests that only read, then you can take advantage of two (logical) load balancers: one that sends all your writes to the master, and one that sends all your read-only requests to a slave."